# Using jQuery to split a div

Tags: jquery, html, split

I essentially need something like this:

```
<div class='one'>Lorem 
   <p>Ipsum 
   <img src="image.jpg" /> 
   sit a</p> lor
</div>
```

to split before and after the image, like this:

```
<div class='one'>Lorem <p>Ipsum</p></div>
<img src="image.jpg" /> 
<div class='one'><p>sit a</p> lor</div>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to do this via string manipulation. First read .html() of the structure, then do all nesessery replacements and finally recreating dom element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OfomehIf/1/)

```
var source = $(".one").html(), 
result = source.replace(/([^<]+<p>[^<]+)(<img[^>]+>)([^<]+<\/p>[^<]+)/im, "$1</p></div>$2<div class='one'><p>$3");
result = result.replace(/\n/ig, " ").replace(/\s+/ig, " ");// this line is optional
$(".one").html(result);
```

Comment: @zzlalani i love the boxes!

Comment: the box is actually for keys like `<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>`

Comment: oh, i know, but can't resist!